# Реализация самого быстрого битового массива

Tags: c++, битовые-операции, соревнование

std::bitset использовать нельзя, таково условие!

Задается непрерывный массив байтов достаточного объема, нужно определить два функционала: считать N-й бит, установить N-й бит

Условия:

- нужно предусмотреть порядок битов (big/litle endian), в некоторых архитектурах он переключаемый, поэтому, сами понимаете, вопрос не простой
- нужно предусмотреть количество битов в байте отличное от восьми
- если надумаете оформлять дефайнами, а не инлайн-функциями, обеспечьте нормальную "безопасность" для коллеги-программера (типа ... передачи в качестве аргумента - аргумента с унарной операцией, возможность защиты от переименования уже существующих программных сущностей)

---

Дабы унифицировать замеры, предлагаю измерять время исполнения единообразно C++ кодом:

```
#include <chrono>
// ...
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// код для замеров < ----------------------------
auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << "Прошло: "
  << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count() 
  << " ms"
  << std::endl;
// ...
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48453/discussion-on-question-by-majestio-----).

Answer (score 5):

Раз вопрос идёт о самой быстрой реализации, то разумеется имеет смысл попробовать реализацию самым простым образом: выделив по `int`'у под каждый бит. Напомню, что об экономичности реализации вопрос не шёл.

Воспользовался кодом @avp, чтобы сравнить скорость. MSVC 2015, Release mode, x64.

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int
main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    const int n = 1000000;
    bitset<1000000> bcp;
    printf("bcp %d\n", (int)sizeof(bcp));

    const unsigned long ebits = (sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT);
    const unsigned long sz = (n + sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT - 1) / ebits;
    unsigned long bc[sz], bysz = sizeof(bc);
    printf("bc  sz = %d ebits = %d bysz = %d\n",
        (int)(sz), (int)ebits, (int)bysz);

    int* crude_array = new int[n];
    printf("crude array size %d\n", n);

    clock_t s, e;
    int nn = 0;

    s = clock();
    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
        srand(9);
        bcp.reset();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            bcp.set(rand() % n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (bcp.test(i))
                nn++;
    }
    e = clock();
    cout << "nn = " << nn << " t = " << e - s << '\n';

    nn = 0;
    s = clock();
    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
        srand(9);
        memset(bc, 0, bysz);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int bi = rand() % n;
            bc[bi / ebits] |= (1UL << (bi % ebits));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (bc[i / ebits] & (1UL << (i % ebits)))
                nn++;
        }
    }
    e = clock();
    cout << "nn = " << nn << " t = " << e - s << '\n';

    nn = 0;
    s = clock();
    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
        srand(9);
        memset(crude_array, 0, sizeof(crude_array));

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int bi = rand() % n;
            crude_array[bi] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (crude_array[i])
                nn++;
        }
    }
    e = clock();
    cout << "nn = " << nn << " t = " << e - s << '\n';
    delete[] crude_array;
}
```

Результат:

```
bcp 125000
bc  sz = 31250 ebits = 32 bysz = 125000
crude array size 1000000
nn = 3276800 t = 2158
nn = 3276800 t = 2067
nn = 3276800 t = 1979
```

Повторные прогоны теста показывают консистентные результаты.

---

Отмечу, что то, что «наивная» реализация оказалась самой быстрой, не так уж самоочевидно. Действительно, у неё страдает cache locality, так что она вполне могла бы оказаться медленнее других. Поэтому совет — в любом случае профилировать, профилировать и ещё раз профилировать код вашего приложения на реальных данных. «Усилием ума» угадать, что будет скорее, нереально (за исключением совсем уж тривиальных случаев).

Answer (score 1):

Просто пример замеров `unsigned long` vs `bitset`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = 1000000;
  bitset<1000000> bcp;
  printf("bcp %d\n", (int)sizeof(bcp));

  unsigned long ebits,
    sz = (n + sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT - 1) / (ebits = (sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT)),
    bc[sz], bysz = sizeof(bc);
  printf("bc  sz = %d ebits = %d bysz = %d\n",
         (int)(sz), (int)ebits, (int)bysz);

  clock_t s, e;
  int nn = 0;

  s = clock();
  for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
    srandom(9);
    bcp.reset();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      bcp.set(random() % n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (bcp.test(i))
        nn++;
  }
  e = clock();
  cout << "nn = " << nn << " t = " << e - s << '\n';

  nn = 0;
  s = clock();
  for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
    srandom(9);
    memset(bc, 0, bysz);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int bi = random() % n;
      bc[bi / ebits] |= (1UL << (bi % ebits));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (bc[i / ebits] & (1UL << (i % ebits)))
        nn++;
    }
  }
  e = clock();
  cout << "nn = " << nn << " t = " << e - s << '\n';
}
```

Опрерации `test` и `set` вытащите в `#define` сами. Аналогично им надо сделать еще `clear` (названия условные).

На всякий случай, вот макросы

```
#define B_SET(a, i) ({__typeof__((a)[0]) *_a = (a); __typeof__(i) _i = (i); \
    _a[_i / (sizeof(_a[0]) * CHAR_BIT)] |= (1UL << (_i % (sizeof(_a[0]) * CHAR_BIT)));})
#define B_CLR(a, i) ({__typeof__((a)[0]) *_a = (a); __typeof__(i) _i = (i); \
    _a[_i / (sizeof(_a[0]) * CHAR_BIT)] &= ~(1UL << (_i % (sizeof(_a[0]) * CHAR_BIT)));})
#define B_TEST(a, i) ({__typeof__((a)[0]) *_a = (a); __typeof__(i) _i = (i); \
    _a[_i / (sizeof(_a[0]) * CHAR_BIT)] & (1UL << (_i % (sizeof(_a[0]) * CHAR_BIT)));})
```

проверял в Linux `g++.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0`

Comment: продолжим тему =) мой вывод - `nn = 63223897 t = 2760
nn = 63223897 t = 2804` я запускал на винде, заменил srandom() на srand и заменил random на `int myrand(){
   return (rand()<<16) + rand();
}` В дебаге битсет проигрывает процентов 30.

Comment: http://ideone.com/uO4VPN вот запускаемый пример.

Comment: @pavel, посмотрел вывод с идеона, ну, значит в винде bitset чуть быстрее (распределение другое? или процессор? или компилятор такой?). Попробовал `unsigned int` (вместо long), т.е. 32 бита. Разницы практически нет. Кстати, vector у меня даже от bitset чуть отстает (т.е. работает дольше). Также попробовал `char cb[n];` по байту на бит. Неожиданно оказалось не быстрее. В 4-х запусках один раз чуть быстрее и 3 чуть медленнее `unsigned int` битовой версии (видимо из-за в 8 раз большей памяти, хотя у меня и 6Mb cache)

Comment: @avp: С `char`'ом на бит, как ни странно, не так быстро. А вот с интом у меня вполне получается быстрее. (Всё-таки `int` нативного размера? Или другой компилятор?)

Comment: @VladD, я не знаю. Наверное зависит от сочетания CPU-компилятор. Вообще удивился, что bitset с константой в template не всегда самый быстрый. Видимо они выход за границу проверяют.

Comment: @avp вроде бы нет. По крайней мере в релизе. А вот число бит для count наверно подсчитывается.

Answer (score 0):

@PashaPash, ok ... продолжим. Сам предложу варианты!

1) Первый

```
#define GETBIT(Array,Num) ((*(Array+(Num/CHAR_BIT))&(1<<(Num%CHAR_BIT)))!=0)
```

2) Второй

```
bool Getbit(void *Array, size_t Num) {
  const int   char_bits = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits;
  return (reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(Array)[Num / char_bits] & 1 << Num % char_bits) != 0;
}
```

3) Третий

```
bool Getbit_other(void *Array, size_t Num) {
  const int char_bits = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits;
  div_t tmp = div(Num, char_bits);
  return (reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(Array)[tmp.quot] & 1<<tmp.rem) != 0;
}
```

Критикуйте. Наверняка где-то косяки с порядком битов будут.
Свои варианты/"патчи" предлагайте ...

Comment: Добавил макросы к ответу

Comment: Код вашего бенчмарка добавили в вопрос, ответ удалён. Всё хорошо, не беспокойтесь, осваивайтесь )